# UITableViewCells have no margin or shadow on tvOS app

Tags: uitableview, tvos

I'm trying to replicate the TableView style seen in the settings app of the Apple TV, but I can't figure out why the default settings for the UITableView don't work.

Here's what my view looks like: [image: Table view with cells that have no shadows]

And here's the view I'm going for: [image: tvos settings app]

My TableView is embedded inside of another UIView, and I've tried tweaking the layout margin control with no affect.

I was looking at this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-tvos-development--cms-24848), which uses table views, and theirs look correct, but don't mention any changes to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if you have "Clip to subview" checked on your cells.  Uncheck it and it should resolve the problem.

[image: Inspector view for table view cell]